# Passing Properties as Default Parameter

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

I'm trying to find an elegant pythonic solution for the following design issue:
Within a class I want to use properties as default parameter. 
So, one could do something like:

```
Class A:

  def __init__(self, a=0, b=1):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def func(self, a=None, b=None):
    a = a or self.a
    b = b or self.b
    # do something with a and b
```

But since this seems like potential boilerplate code, I went ahead and wrote a generic function outside of my class.

```
def fallback_parameters(obj, **args):
    return [args[arg] or getattr(obj, arg) for arg in args]
```

and use

```
def func(self, a=None, b=None):
    a, b = fallback_parameters(self, a=a, b=b)
    # do something with a and b
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this? An existing solution?
I'm tempted to create a decorator, so I don't need to type something like:

```
a, b, c, d, e = fallback_parameters(self, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e)
```

Comment: I am sure there is a solution. But I am not sure about what your problem is. What is the purpose of `func`? Because just using a and b will not affect the object state. Also `self.a` and `self.b` are easily accessible from anywhere in your object. Does func serve to update self.a and self.b?

Comment: @progmatico
What func does is not relevant.
Let's just say func does some computation and uses default values self.a and self.b if i just call func(). 
The whole idea is to have default-args but define them when creating the class-object.

Comment: @progmatico Func does not change properties.

Comment: I added a link to an introspection example at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for illustration if you wanted it to change the object instance attibute (you say you do not) the decorator would be like this:

```
def fallback_args(func):

    def inner(obj, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            for key in kwargs:
                setattr(obj, key, kwargs[key])
        return func(obj, **kwargs)
    return inner

class B:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @fallback_args
    def func(self, a=None, b=None):
        print("Do something with {} and {}".format(self.a, self.b))
        #or
        #a = self.a
        #b = self.b
        #print("Do something with {} and {}".format(a, b))

obj2 = B()
print(obj2.a)
print(obj2.b)
obj2.func()

print()

obj2 = B()
print(obj2.a)
print(obj2.b)
obj2.func(a=300)

print()

print(obj2.a)
print(obj2.b)
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
Do something with 0 and 1

0
1
Do something with 300 and 1

300
1
```

But not wanting to change the object, I don't think it makes sense just to avoid
explicit `a = self.a or a` like lines. Because if you don't list the parameters in the call, how would the decorator know what names do you mention in the methods' body to fallback/load them? You can say, the names are only the ones listed in the method signature. Now, that can be introspected, but I think I am seeing more convoluted work here than this deserves. `a = self.a or a` looks simple and explicit. So it is Pythonic too, although you probably could write the implicit assignment you want with some more work.

For an idea on how to introspect method args see a somewhat related decorator I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611213/how-to-freeze-some-arguments-over-multiple-related-class-methods/56612318#56612318) to freeze methods args.